# How about a draggable splitter bar (or whatever it's called)?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

This may not even be feasible, but I figure it's worth asking. I was looking at  [this question about SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql) and I noticed I was doing the following:

1. Scroll up to look at the data tables.
2. Scroll down to look at the code in the answer.
3. Repeat.

I ended up copying the data and answer code into notepad to view it more easily.

So my request is a movable "splitter bar" like you would have in Excel, etc. so you can better view different parts of the screen together.

Comment: Ah! We programmers are a lazy lot. That's why we write programs to do stuff for us. :) Seriously though, it's not a bad idea from a usablilty stand-point, but we're having a hard enough time getting them to implement a "copy code" feature.

Comment: I think it might be a good idea for a script.